# escaping $ in csh

Tags: shell, csh

How can I escape `$` in csh? inside <double-quotes> (`""`). I'm trying to do this but can't escape the <dollar> sign (`$`)

```
alias e "echo \\!:2-$"
```

This works but is not enough for my needs

```
alias e echo \\!:2-$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers suggested to this old question aren't correct.

It *can* be done, in CSH and other shells, and regardless of the kind of quote, but you need to exit the double quotes first if using them, for some shells.

The following should work in (almost) all shells, so I use it for simplicity. I've used backquote to get the output of a command because it's simpler to follow and avoids needing to add extra "$" symbols (the more modern style). Note the different uses of "$", to actually get a variable and as a literal (inside and outside single quotes for ease).

This should work in most shells.

**EXAMPLE COMMAND:**

```
echo "My terminal is $term, first file found in /dev is </dev/`ls /dev | head -n 1`>, the
dollar symbol is '"`echo '$'`"', and a newspaper costs "`echo '$'`"2.50."
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
My terminal is xterm, first file found in /dev is </dev/acpi>, the dollar symbol
is '$', and a newspaper costs $2.50.
```

Comment: The last double quotes around 2.50 are not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Trying using single quotes instead - `alias e 'echo \!:2-$'`.  You also need to backslash escape the history substitution as well.

Comment: This works fine I just want to point out ther is no solution to escaping the $ sign inside "".

Comment: @PabloKarlsson - that is essentially the difference between single and double quotes.  The latter allows for substitutions such as variable expansions and special characters where the former one disables (most) substitutions.

Comment: I have an expression that's like:

f=some/path; ssh foo@bar "$f | thing && echo Success || echo Failure, exit code $?"

I need the double quotes for the $f, but I want the $? to be passed through to the remote host for evaluation. I've tried \$?, but that'd doesn't work. Does csh have a different means of escaping $?

Comment: @bobpaul, to echo the $? status in the context of the shell running on the remote, end your double quoted string just before the $? and use '$?' instead.  You are concatenating two strings - one using double quotes with the second using single quotes (to avoid the dollar expansion.  Like: `f=some/path; ssh foo@bar "$f | thing && echo Success || echo Failure, exit code "'$?'`.  Of course, if it's csh, you have to use `set` to set the `f` variable - do `set f=some/path` rather than `f=some/path`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use a `$` character inside a double quoted string, then try setting a variable (ideally in your ~/.tcshrc file) to the character.

For example, here's an alias that creates sequentially numbered backup files in the format "filename.old24.ext" given the command `bak filename ext`:

```
set DOLLAR='$'
alias bak '/bin/ls -1v \!:1.old*.\!:2 | tail -n 1 | awk -F"." "{printf substr(${DOLLAR}2,4)+1}" | xargs -0 -ISEQ cp -ip \!:1.\!:2 \!:1.oldSEQ.\!:2'
```

Notice, the use of `${DOLLAR}` in the string passed to awk. It will be replaced by an actual `$` character when the alias is executed by the shell.